# Dynamically creating aliases in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, alias

I'd like to create some aliases dynamically but I can't get my code to work. Here's the code:

```
# Drives
$drives = ("a","b","c","d","e")
foreach ($drive in $drives) {
    New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.GetNewClosure()
}

function GoToDrive($drive) {
    $formatted = "$($drive):\"
    if (Test-Path $formatted) {
        Set-Location $formatted
    } else {
        Write-Host "`"$formatted`" does not exist."
    }
}
```

When I type "a", or "b", or any of the letters in $drives, it should change my working directory to that drive's letter (e.g.: A:).

The error I'm getting now is this:

```
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'a'.
At C:\Users\prubi\OneDrive\Documentos\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:17 char:5
+     New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.Ge ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'b'.
At C:\Users\prubi\OneDrive\Documentos\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:17 char:5
+     New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.Ge ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'c'.
At C:\Users\prubi\OneDrive\Documentos\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:17 char:5
+     New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.Ge ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'd'.
At C:\Users\prubi\OneDrive\Documentos\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:17 char:5
+     New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.Ge ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'e'.
At C:\Users\prubi\OneDrive\Documentos\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:17 char:5
+     New-Item -Path alias:\ -Name $drive -Value GoToDrive($drive) #.Ge ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Can anybody help me get this to work, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is that PowerShell is interpreting `-Value GoToDrive($drive)` as specifying the switch `-Value 'GoToDrive'` and also a positional parameter `$drive`. (This is bizarre and unintuitive, yes.) Enclosing `GoToDrive($drive)` in parentheses would try to call the as-yet-nonexistent `GoToDrive` function and then use the results as the argument for `-Value`, which is not what you're after even if `GoToDrive` had been defined previously. Another problem is that aliases cannot supply arguments to the command they call; they are only alternate names for commands.

You need to dynamically execute commands that create the shortcut functions:

```
# This is the exact same GoToDrive function you've been using
function GoToDrive($drive) {
    $formatted = "$($drive):\"
    if (Test-Path $formatted) {
        Set-Location $formatted
    } else {
        Write-Host "`"$formatted`" does not exist."
    }
}

# This does the magic
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' | % {iex "function $_ {GoToDrive '$_'}"}
```

[`Invoke-Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6), or `iex` for short, runs its determined-at-runtime argument as if you had typed it on the command line yourself. So that last line executes `function a {GoToDrive 'a'}`, then `function b {GoToDrive 'b'}`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification and for the working code! I'm accepting yours as the right answer.